# How to create a table of random 0's and 1's (with weights) in Excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to create a random, square table of 0's and 1's like so

```
0  1  0
0  0  1
0  1  0
```

but only bigger (around 14 x 14). The diagonal should be all 0's and the table should be symmetric across the diagonal. For example, this would not be good:

```
0  1  1
0  0  0
0  1  0
```

I would also like to have control over the number of `1` 's that appear, or at least the probability that `1`'s appear.

I only need to make a few such tables, so this does not have to be fully automated by any means. I do not mind at all doing a lot of the work by hand.

If possible, I would greatly prefer doing this without coding in VBA (small code in cells is okay of course) since I do not know it at all.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot that the diagonal should be all 0's.

Comment: Your first example isn't symmetric over the diagonal.

Comment: And, does this help `=IF(RAND()>Threshold,1,0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Edit**: amended so as to return a symmetrical array, as requested by the OP*.

`=LET(λ,RANDARRAY(ξ,ξ),IF(1-MUNIT(ξ),GESTEP(MOD(MMULT(λ,TRANSPOSE(λ)),1),1-ζ),0))`

where ξ is the side length of the returned square array and ζ is an approximation as to the probability of a non-diagonal entry within that array being unity.

As ξ increases, so does the accuracy of ζ.

Comment: Well done for the use of obtuse characters. Interesting formula. It doesn't give the symmetry the OP was looking for though.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks, forgot about the symmetry part. Will try to revise. Hopefully I mistook the intention of your comment re my choice of characters - they're certainly not obtuse to mathematicians, nor to the Greeks for that matter!

Comment: No, I like the use of those characters. It makes it more interesting. I have to use `charmap` to type them in windows so they are generally more work, but they look nice. I like using `λ`. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to quantify how good the approximation is to the probability of a one off the diagonal? It looks a bit tricky to me as you're effectively squaring the uniform random numbers then modding them, but it might be a piece of math I'm unaware of.

Comment: @TomSharpe If it is then it's beyond my knowledge. As you point out, it's not clear whether the operations I'm applying to a uniformly distributed set result in another uniformly distributed set.